# Creating variably named arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I appreciate I may not be expressing myself clearly - apologies,  I have a company details screen which also displays all/any drills the company may be invested in.  For each of these drills I wish to display a drop down list of any drill assumptions the user may have saved.  Below is the relvent code.
From the controller

```
...
@drill_interests = @company.drill_interests
first_index = 0
@drill_interests.each do |di|
  @array_name = "eval_assum" + first_index.to_s
  @array_name = Array.new
  @matched_eval_assum = 
    EvaluationAssumption.matched_eval_assum(@current_user.id,  di.drill_id)
  second_index = 0
  if @matched_eval_assum.present?
    @matched_eval_assum.each do |mea|
      data_for_select = {"id" => second_index, "name" => mea.user_save_name, 
            "table_index" => mea.id,}
      @array_name = @array_name << data_for_select
      second_index += 1
    end
  else
    puts "no matches found"
  end 
  first_index += 1 
end
```

Endevouring to create arrays eg. eval_assum0, eval_assu1 etc which have 0 to many hashes of id, name and table index.
Having set trace statements I know I am looping through the data in the expected manner.  However my attempts to access the arrays, see below, seem to indicate I haven't built the array as expected.  It seems "eval_assum0" is a string (not an array).  What have I done wrong ? 
As always thanks in advance - Pierre

```
...    <% index = 0 %>
...
    <% @array_name = "eval_assum" + index.to_s %>
      <%= select("name", "id",
          @array_name.collect {|r| [ r["user_save_name"], r["id"] ] },
          { :include_blank => true })  %>
```

Further carification.
So for example company EML is invested in two drill - (eg. drill-01 and drill-02).  The user has saved 2 evaluation_assumptions for drill-01 and 3 evaluation assumptions for drill-02 .  Of course a company canhave invested in 0 to many drills.
On Eml page next to Drill-01 trying to create adrop down list (with two selections) and next to Drill-03 (hree selections.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generically speaking *variable names are not variable*. Setting the `@array_name` to `"eval_assum" + index.to_s` does just that - `@array_name` is now a *String with value `"eval_assum0"`*, **not** an array called `eval_assum0`.

If you want a set of dynamically named arrays, I would suggest you use a container to hold them, like a `Hash`:

```
@assumptions = {}
@drill_interests = @company.drill_interests
first_index = 0
@drill_interests.each do |di|
  array_name = "eval_assum" + first_index.to_s

  # set the array inside the hash
  @assumptions[array_name] = Array.new

  @matched_eval_assum = 
    EvaluationAssumption.matched_eval_assum(@current_user.id,  di.drill_id)
  second_index = 0
  if @matched_eval_assum.present?
    @matched_eval_assum.each do |mea|
      data_for_select = {"id" => second_index, "name" => mea.user_save_name, 
            "table_index" => mea.id,}

      # fill the array inside the hash
      @assumptions[array_name] << data_for_select

      second_index += 1
    end
  else
    puts "no matches found"
  end 
  first_index += 1 
end
```

and

```
...    <% index = 0 %>
...
    <% array_name = "eval_assum" + index.to_s %>
      <%= select("name", "id",
          @assumptions[array_name].collect {|r| [ r["user_save_name"], r["id"] ] },
          { :include_blank => true })  %>
```

Comment: Liri - thanks for answer.  Working on it but so far no luck.  Have also added extra explanation.  Thanks - Pierre

Comment: @user1854802 - can you expand on "no luck"?

Comment: On screen I get the same collection_seection twice.  Will put current screen code in above.

Comment: now working - I wasn't incrementing counter for collection select.  Thanks - Pierre